# Playing Age of Empires II multiplayer in VirtualBox Over wi fi network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, games, connection

I installed **Age of Empires II (Expansion)** in **VirtualBox** (hosting Windows XP). It works great in single player mode. Unfortunately, I tried playing multiplayer via WI-FI which I created on my Ubuntu machine and can't seem to join games.

But when I connected to my WI-FI router other able to connect to my system and we can play multiplayer mode 
This is what I've done so far to try to resolve the issue:

1. *I noticed that the IP address of my virtual machine was 10.0.x.x,
   While the local IP on Ubuntu is 192.168.x.x, which I figured was a
   Problem. So I changed from NAT networking to bridged networking in
   VirtualBox .*
   [image]
2. *I turned off the Windows firewall in the virtual machine and don't have any ports blocked by Ubuntu, so no software firewall should be at fault.*

However I'm still unable to play multiplayer games, and suspect that some kind of networking issue lies at the heart of the problem. I'm not sure what else I would need to change, however.

So essentially I was wondering if anyone else here has managed to play AOE2, or any similar game, inside VirtualBox from Ubuntu, and if so what you needed to do to make it possible. Or if anyone has suggestions on where else to look to figure out the problem, I'd appreciate that as well. Unfortunately AOE2 itself doesn't provide any debugging information to troubleshoot the inability to connect to network games.
Here MY IP result both for Ubuntu and Virtualbox XP 
[image: XP Ipconfig]
[image: Ubuntu IfCOnfig]

I want to play game on multiplayer mode in virtualbox on my system(Own Created on Ubuntu ) wi-fi on which other can connect and play hope someone will answer this

Comment: Does your virtual XP connect intertet normally? For example to visit some websites.

Comment: Rock on with Age of Empires, but try out 0AD it is pretty good and similar to Age of Empires and works on Ubuntu.  Plus it is free.

Comment: @Misery , Yes i am Connected to internet on NAT and on Bridged mode . But when i am connected to my wireless router . here i am creating my own wi-fi network which don't have any internet.

Comment: It got a gold rating on winehq: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=99 This whole virtualbox issue is a moot point.

Comment: Just use Voobly or Gameranger to play
I know Voobly works, haven't tested Gameranger

Comment: remove the nat, you want the bridge mode which will make the vb look like it is a new machine to the dhcp of your router. But there might be other things which need to be done. Get rid of the nat first and make sure you can ping the vb from outside (another computer or laptop). If this works come back to me and I'll help you find out the rest, e.g. check and open blocked ports, and so on